adding buttons to a PyQT/Matplotlib NavigationToolbar2QT
I've successfully added a button to the standard navigation toolbar using the following function, however my new button appears at the right side of the toolbar, and I would like it to follow the existing buttons on the left side. I can't find any reference to positioning or aligning the buttons.
I'm guessing the reason is that there is a QSpacerItem added to the layout, but how do I squeeze my button in before it?
def add_toolbar(self):
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self, True)
    self.measure_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.toolbar)
    self.measure_button.clicked.connect(self.measure)
    self.measure_button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('MyButtonIcon.jpg'))
    self.toolbar.addWidget(self.measure_button)
    self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolbar)


It's not recommended to modify the NavigationToolbar2QT, because  it may be broken in the future.
If you insist to do that, you can do like the following for the current version. (The last action(or widget) of the original toolbar is a label filling the remaining space.)
    self.toolbar.insertWidget(self.toolbar.actions()[-1],
        self.measure_button)


This works but you've got the syntax slightly wrong. It should be 'self.toolbar.actions()[-1]'. I can't imagine that the insertWidget function will disappear in future versions so I think it will be safe.

Corrected a typo. Thanks. And I said a risk on the future version for Matplotlib, not for Qt.
